# Comma separated KeyValue Pipe in Angular

Tags: angular

In Angular 12, I am using a keyvalue pipe to loop through an object. I want to add a comma at the end of each value, if there is more than one and not add it to the last one. This code seems to add it to the last one too. How do I fix it?

```
results: {
  "Status": "Disabled",
  "Preference": "Enabled",
  "Security": "Enabled",
  "Profile": "Disabled"
}

<div *ngFor="let item of results | keyvalue; index as i">
  {{item.key}}:&nbsp;{{item.value}}
  <span *ngIf="i != item.length-1">,&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `index` you can you the `last` variable of `*ngFor` directive. Your code should look like this then:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of results | keyvalue; last as isLast">
  {{item.key}}:&nbsp;{{item.value}}
  <span *ngIf="!isLast">,&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

There are also a bunch of other variables too:

`index`
`first`
`last`
`even`
`odd`